# Polymer back button doesn't work with hash routing

Tags: javascript, polymer, url-routing, polymer-1.0

Sup! Back button sometimes doesn't work with my polymer project. When i hit back button the `page` variable is steel the current page and i need to hit the button twice or three times to get it working for example i go to the `/#/rules` page from `/#/home` but it doesn't go back to `/#/home` once i press the back button the second or third time by the way it does go back to the main page. Here is my observer and router:

```
properties: {
    page: {
        type: String,
        reflectToAttribute: true,
        observer: '_pageChanged',
    },
},

observers: [
    '_routePageChanged(routeData.page)',
],

_routePageChanged: function (page) {
        this.page = page || 'home';
        this.set('route.path', `/${this.page}`);
},

_pageChanged: function (page) {
    // Load page import on demand. Show 404 page if fails
    var resolvedPageUrl = this.resolveUrl(page + '.html');
    this.importHref(resolvedPageUrl, null, this._showPage404, true);
    window.history.pushState({}, null, `#/${this.page}`);
},
```

And this is my `app-route` element:

```
<app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/:page" data="{{routeData}}" tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>
```

Just can't figure out why it does not work the first time. Any help is appreciated and i have already searched a lot with no results.

Answer (score 10):

Can you try this, assuming you have `<app-route route="{{route}}"></app-route>`?

```
observers: [
    '_routePageChanged(route.path)',
],

_routePageChanged: function(path) {
    if (path) {
        this.page = this.routeData.page;
    } else {
        /*
         * It's unnecessary to have the following line.
         */
        // this.page = 'home';
        this.set('route.path', '/home');
    }
},
```

**Why it works after all?**

I learned my lesson by debugging the source code of `<app-route>`. If the path is empty, the code for updating `data` will be skipped - and your observer, `_routePageChanged(routeData.page)`, won't be triggered. See

- https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-route/blob/master/app-route.html#L254-L257
- https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-route/blob/master/app-route.html#L320-L328

You may consider it to be a flaw in `<app-route>`. Whatsoever, it's open source, and you can always find your way.

Comment: This is the answer ! Thanks

Comment: The line, `this.page = 'home';`, can be omitted.

Comment: @PooyaRaki Thank you for pushing the question with a bounty. Please read the updated answer, and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: so he just ask a question, and then remove self without mark this as answer?